# Use Pandas to sort a dataframe by date with NaN in other columns

Tags: pandas

I have two tables that store data of different time periods, e.g. 2017-2018 and 2015-2018.  I tried to merge them by the 'Date' column:

`combined = pd.merge(table a, table b, on='Date', how='outer')`

However, as the date ranges are different (the first table is smaller than the second one), there are NaN in the combined table that makes sorting by date difficult.

i.e. if certain dates are not in table a, the table a columns will display NaN and these rows will move to the end of the combined table.

I tried to do the sorting using

`combined.sort_values(by='Date', ascending=True)`

but to no avail.

Could anyone tell me how the sorting can be done ?

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: `sort_values()` has a `na_position` parameter. It is `last` by default, but you can change it to `first` if that helps. Also, you could use `fillna()` and fill all `NaT`s with a default value , and then sort.

Comment: What's the datatype of the `Date` column?

Comment: Thanks chillin and Dark.  The datatype is datetime64[ns].  About the sorting issue, actually it was slightly more complicated than I described -  the two tables have different number of dates even for the same year.  For example, the first dataset may cover 22, 24 and 26/8; whereas the second covers 22-26/8.  And I was hoping to keep the 23/8 and 25/8 rows in the middle of the table.  Hope this clarifies.  Thanks again.

Comment: Just to eliminate the obvious, you are assigning the result of `sort_values()` to something, right? e.g. either `combined = combined.sort_values(by='Date', ascending=True)` or `combined.sort_values(by='Date', ascending=True, inplace=True)`?

Comment: I love you chillin ^3^    Guys please forgive my ignorance - I saw df.sort_values somewhere in the google results and thought that would suffice.  Thanks for eliminating the 'not-so-obvious-to-me' for me.  You all are amazing and I wish you a wonderful year ahead :)

Comment: No problem and same to you